# Best way for registration which prevents anti automation

Tags: email, security, automation, registration, captcha

On my webservice, I have a registration form where the user can register with email address, username and password. For anti-automation, I send a confirmation-link to the email address.

This is how most of the webservices do it.
But I´m thinking to go away from that email mechanism and simply use a captcha instead to prevent automated registrations.

What are the pros / cons of these two approaches regarding security and usability? And are there other mechanisms for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Email confirmation can be easily automated, it's more to ensure that it's a real address the user has access to (though doesn't guarantee it).

Comment: Thanks. I currently use the email only for password reset. So if the user doesn´t enter a real address, he would not be able to do so. But that´s his own fault :-)

Comment: Yes, which is most famously done by Reddit! No email required to register. (At least that used to be the case.)